# Is the new Gmail home button available?

Tags: android, user-interface, gmail

I'm looking for the new Gmail home button UI. Which now displays 3 bars at the left of the app icon.
I think it's a really good way to show the user the the menu is hided on the side of the main display !

Maybe some of you guys have an idea for getting this.

Thanks !

[image]

edit :

All is here, thanks for helping : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the new [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) pattern. You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: Okay thanks, I didn't see the part about the App icon... My bad !

But thanks again for pointing it out !